# How to set the id to the index of the v-for loop

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, indexing, tags

Can't figure out how to set the id to the index of the v-for loop.

I've tried:

```
<li v-for="(item, index) in items" v-bind:key="item.id">
   <p>{{item.name}}</p>
   <input id= {{index}} type= "number">
</li>
```

```
<li v-for="(item, index) in items" v-bind:key="item.id">
   <p>{{item.name}}</p>
   <input id= index type= "number">
</li>
```

And many other variations but it would not work. Would appreciate help!

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to add `item-index` like `item-1`, `item-2`, to avoid id confliction.

Try using Template literals, like: `myname-${index}`.

Don't forge the "``".

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```
<li v-for="(item, index) in items" v-bind:key="item.id">
   <input v-bind:id="`yourname-${index}`" type= "number">
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `v-bind:id` like below:

```
<li v-for="(item, index) in items" v-bind:key="item.id">
   <input v-bind:id="index" type= "number">
</li>
```

Comment: I tried this but when I called the id for e.g. #1{...} in css, the changes will not appear..

Answer (score 1):

For css response use some string at the begining of id structure as below:

```html
<li v-for="(item, index) in items" v-bind:key="item.id">
    <input v-bind:id="'str' + index" type="number">
</li>
```